# Which type of tower is best?

Tags: castle-clash

So, I have started to farm Here Be Monsters. I am in awe at how people are on wave T and I can't get past wave F. I have been looking at their bases and noticed they all use Magic Towers. So my question is, are Magic Towers better than Watchtowers? I have always been told Watchtowers are superior, but I'm starting to question that theory.

Comment: With the right garrisons of high enough level (green I think), Magic Towers can stun enemies. I suspect the tactic exploits this by attempting to perma-stun incoming enemies. Only speculation on my part though, I've not yet finished I.

Comment: @JonK Do you use Magic Towers?

Comment: Not at the moment, no. I am considering changing that though

Comment: Minor correction to my first comment - it's the blue garrisons that grant stun chance to magic towers. Green garrisons increase attack rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow towers do the most damage while Magic towers can stun the enemy units.

Thus it depends on what type of assistance you need. Would you prefer stunning enemies or inflicting damage?

Cannon towers are pretty useless except for the earlier levels when you are farming HBM D and below.